# Remove Shadow of Floating action button programmatically

Tags: android, listview, floating-action-button

I am using FAB in my listview layout with a delete icon. Now what iam doing is that there is a main FAB in layout but when any list view item is long pressed then contextual action bar showed up and also the FAB changed to "select all" icon so that user can select all items when clicked on FAB. But the problem is that when i changed my FAB to another FAB then the shadow of FAB becomes darker. I know this is because the first FAB is still behind the second FAB. so what should i do to remove the shadow so that even if second FAB is above first FAB the shadow doesnot show. Here is my code in Oncreate for FAB.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mainm);
FloatingActionButton fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
.withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aaqw))
.withButtonColor(Color.parseColor("#E3564C"))
.withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT)
.withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
.create();
```

and here I am changing to another FAB.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual, menu);
        FloatingActionButton fabButtonn = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(AfterTab.this)
        .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selectall))

        .withButtonColor(Color.parseColor("#E3564C"))
        .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT)

        .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
        .create();

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        FloatingActionButton fabButtonnn = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(AfterTab.this)
        .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aaqw))
        .withButtonColor(Color.parseColor("#E3564C"))
        .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT)
        .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
        .create();
    }
```

so basically i again show the first FAB when onDestroy method called.
But shadow obviously becomes darker. How to solve this issue or is there any way to remove first FAB and then show second and then remove second and again show first?

Comment: Why you don't set the visibility of the first one to INVISIBLE?

Comment: I tried with this too.I put final in the beginning of first FAB declaration and then in the onCreateActionMode method I set the visibility of First Fab to invisible and it works well. But in the onDestroyActionMode method i want to set the visibilty of second FAB gone and first FAB again visible. Now here first FAB is again visible but second FAB visibilty  is not going to be gone as the "fabButtonn" is inside the method and no way to access it :(

Comment: @Chol what to do sir?

Comment: Is it not possible to declare the FABs outside the methods and then initialize them inside the methods?

Comment: @IshitaSinha lemme try this sir

Comment: *madam. Not "sir". ;)

Comment: @Chol problem solved

Comment: @IshitaSinha Thank you mam i declare outside method and initialize in the method and it works

Comment: Glad you solved it :)